# Recordset Not Updating Table with Changed and/or Correct Values

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, recordset

The codes purpose is to *'build'* the correct name style for each record in a **CDSal** and **FormatName** field. I have a group of tables (all linked) with individuals Full Name(NewName), Salutation, First, Middle and Last Name, as well as Client defaults for what to do with those names (!NewName, !First, !AA, etc.).

The Recordset is pulled from a query in the database that brings some necessary fields together from 2 different tables. From Access I can open the query, make any changes needed to any of the fields, save the record and see the changes reflected in the underlying tables. When I run the following code, the Debug.Print's produce the expected outcomes but nothing is *permanently* saved to the tables. The code never errors (which might be part of the problem) and for Case "!AA" both CDSal and FormatName fields are filled with !NewName when Debug.Print again shows the expected outcome. Case "!AA" is the only instance where anything is actually changed on the tables.

I have attempted everything that I could find on the Internet to troubleshoot this error as well as multiple different configurations to get something to "stick". Hopefully it is a simple answer, let me know what you all think.

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
On Error GoTo Form_Load_Err

'_ SetUp Variables _'
Dim strQry As String, strSQL As String, strName As String
Dim rstName As DAO.Recordset

'_ Declare Variables _'
strQry = "MyQueryName"
Set rstName = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strQry, dbOpenDynaset)

'_ Begin Code _'
    With rstName
    If Not (.EOF And .BOF) Then .MoveFirst
    Do Until .EOF = True
'Update CDSal with correct Naming Information
Debug.Print !NewName
    .Edit
    Select Case !CDSal_Client
    Case "NewName"     'Clients that use NewName for blah
        !CDSal = !NewName
    Case "First"       'Clients that use First for blah
        !CDSal = !First
    Case "AA"          'ClientName: CDSal = First, FormatName = NewName(w/o Sal)
        !CDSal = !First
        If !Sal <> "" Then
            !FormatName = !First & " " & !Middle & " " & !Last
        Else
            !FormatName = !NewName
        End If
    Case "BB"          'ClientName: Client uses specific breakdown for names
        If !Sal <> "" And !Last <> "" Then
            !CDSal = !Sal & " " & !Last
            !FormatName = !Sal & " " & !Last
        ElseIf !First <> "" And !Last <> "" Then
            !CDSal = !First & " " & !Last
            !FormatName = !First & " " & !Last
        ElseIf !First <> "" Then
            !CDSal = !First
            !FormatName = !First
        Else
            !CDSal = "Valued Member"
            !FormatName = "Valued Member"
        End If
    Case "CC"          'ClientName: CDSal = NewName(trim " & " if needed) = NewName + AddlName(done on import)
        If Right(!NewName, 3) = " & " Then
            Replace !NewName, " & ", ""
            !CDSal = !NewName
        Else
            !CDSal = !NewName
        End If
    End Select
    .Update
Debug.Print !CDSal
Debug.Print !FormatName
    .MoveNext
    Loop
'Removes additional spaces left over from concatenating fields
strSQL = "UPDATE [" & strQry & "] SET [FormatName] = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE([FormatName],' ','<>'),'><',''),'<>',' '), " & _
            "[CDSal] = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE([FormatName],' ','<>'),'><',''),'<>',' ');"
    CurrentDb.Execute strSQL
    End With
'_ Error Handling & CleanUp
Form_Load_ClnUp:
    rstName.Close
    Set rstName = Nothing
    Exit Sub
Form_Load_Err:
    MsgBox Err.SOURCE & " : " & Err.Number & vbCr & _
        "Error Description : " & Err.Description
    GoTo Form_Load_ClnUp
End Sub
```

**MyQueryName SQL**

```
SELECT T_Individual.ID_IndivRecords, T_Individual.NewName, T_Individual.NewName2, T_Individual.CDSal, T_Individual.FormatName, T_Individual.Status_, T_Individual.Sal, T_Individual.First, T_Individual.Middle, T_Individual.Last, T_Clients.ID_Client, T_Clients.CDSal_Client, T_Individual.Date
FROM T_Individual INNER JOIN (T_Clients INNER JOIN (T_Jobs INNER JOIN T_IndivJobs ON T_Jobs.ID_Jobs = T_Individual.Jobs) ON T_Clients.ID_Client = T_Jobs.Client) ON T_Individual.ID_IndivRecords = T_IndivJobs.ID_DonorRecords
WHERE (((T_Individual.Date)=Date()));
```

Comment: `Select Case !CDSal_Client` will return `NewName` NOT `!NewName`, just remove the `!` from all the Cases, NewName, First, AA, BB, CC

Comment: I would add Case Else to your Select...End Select and put a MsgBox("I didn't expect to get here.") in there.  It could be that like @RicardoA is theorizing, the values in your CDSal_Client field don't match up to the values in your Case statements.  Also I note that in your code your query name is called MyStringName (?!) but you've posted SQL for a query called MyQueryName.  Finally I would note  that you can alternatively refer to fields in recordsets with the syntax Recordset.Fields("FieldName") which would allow you to use a string variable in place of "FieldName" if you wanted to.

Comment: @RicardoA, The data in the underlying table is actually stored with the "!". That is a remnant from a previous iteration of handling this same issue. I can see how this can be confusing moving from the outside and for my future self and will remove the "!" from the data.

Comment: @deluxeinformation, That sounds like a good error handling and will definitely add that to the end to be sure the user is notified if something went wrong. I'll probably need to kill the code at that point as 1,000s of names will be running at the same time and the user might get stuck if any majority of them reach this and results in equal # of MsgBox's. The Query name difference is an oversight as I was posting this, my employer has asked for any identifying naming conventions be changed to protect privacy. Will edit to correct name difference. I will also take a stab at Rst.Field("Field").

Comment: I have attempted the possible solutions mentioned above. The code runs as normal with the updated !CDSal_Client field no longer having "!". I changed all instances of "!FieldName" to ".Fields("FieldName")" and was able to run the code with no errors. However, the code produced the same outcome as before and ran significantly slower, roughly 2 seconds over ~350 records. I will update the code in the original post to reflect any changes, I will be keeping the field references as "!FieldName for now.

Comment: @JamesCrafton, my suggestion was more of a quick and dirty way to make sure your select case was doing what you thought it was doing, although it is definitely a good practice to have a 'case else' to trap unexpected outcomes.  I wouldn't leave that message box in the middle of a loop like that for the end user to possibly pop up hundreds or thousands of times.  And yes, the .Fields("FieldName") will run a bit slower but allowing use of a string to identify the field name can sometimes result in more manageable code.

Answer (score 0):

```
strSQL = "UPDATE [" & strQry & "] SET [FormatName] = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE([FormatName],' ','<>'),'><',''),'<>',' '), " & _
            "[CDSal] = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE([FormatName],' ','<>'),'><',''),'<>',' ');"
```

Another instance of a simple error and or mistype can drastically affect everything you are trying to achieve. This SQL was ran after the code was processed to remove any double spaces that might have been in the original data or created from concatenation. Notice that the CDSal field will be replaced with the FormatName field in the last line instead of being replaced with itself. Since most records do not use the FormatName field their CDSal field was getting replaced with NULL . . .
I have corrected this issue and everything runs very smoothly and correctly now.
Thanks for everyone who tried to help on this! Any additional information on Formatting or Optimization is always appreciated.